# How to recover encrypted deja-dup backup from new install?

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup, encryption, restore, deja-dup

I have a backup of my documents stored in the Ubuntu One cloud. I used the default deja-dup backup application and I have enabled encyption.

I was running Ubuntu 13.04 daily build but as the school projects started to be a bit more important I was clever enough to turn to the latest LTS version, which is where I am now.

The question is, how do I recover the backups done by my previous installation on my current setup?

I have tried using the deja-dup app and choose "restore" and paste the URL to the backup into it, but then it says "There is no backup to restore" (or similar, I'm on a danish translation).

The Url which I am trying to recover from looks like this:
~/deja-dup/Thinkpad-4-Semester

And that is the same URL I see if I use the web-interface from one.ubuntu.com to look at my backup. Unfortunately there is no option to download the files from the web-interface(probably because the encryption, dough...), the only options I have available there is "Share Folder" and "Stop syncing this folder".

Appreciate all help
Thanks :)

Comment: the Ubuntu One files service is discontinued